# How to simplify the same classes on click without copy pasting the same code?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 click event listeners one is for toggle and second for remove class. Now, I don't want to repeat my code over and over again but instead, I would like to have a clean & dry approach to the same goal.

As you can see i have some classes but the only actual difference is toggle and remove.
Is there a cleaner way of doing such a thing?

My JS:

```
    const onNavOpen = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        body.classList.toggle('nav-body-is-open');
        body.classList.toggle('bg-overlay');
        navigationHamburger.classList.toggle('active');
        navigationMenu.classList.toggle('nav--open');
    };

    const onNavClose = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (
            body.classList.contains('nav-body-is-open') &&
            e.keyCode === 27
        ) {
            body.classList.remove('nav-body-is-open');
            body.classList.remove('bg-overlay');
            navigationHamburger.classList.remove('active');
            navigationMenu.classList.remove('nav--open');
        }
    };
```

Comment: Um.. the above code would make sense if you were using add and remove, but toggle alrerady does what you are trying to do, so making the remove function is redundant

Comment: Yeah helped me a lot thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function object that points to either `remove` or `toggle` function based on condition.

Something like below. (Note - I haven't tested the code)

```
const resolvedFunction = body.classList.contains('nav-body-is-open') && e.keyCode === 27 ? body.classList.remove : body.classList.toggle;

resolvedFunction('nav-body-is-open');
resolvedFunction('bg-overlay');
resolvedFunction('active');
resolvedFunction('nav--open');
```